# namespace in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am a beginer to zend. I want to know about namespaces.

- what this code means?

  $a=new Zend_Session_Namespace(Zend_Registry::get('session_variable'));

please help me.

Comment: Here's a great resource for namespaces ....google.

Comment: While this isn't exactly a great question, there's no need to be rude. At least point the OP in the direction of helpful material. @Shaheer, shapeshifter Not understanding namespaces is not an unreasonable position.

Comment: without knowing the meaning of that code, i can not continue through my code review..as i said earlier im a beginer in zend..jst a few days experience is their.thats why i asked the question..there was no need to be rude..thanks again shaheer.. @shaheer

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude. Your first two questions can be typed straight into google and the top results are excellent resourses.  Your third you need to know what the Zend Registry returns and how that is used by Zend_Session_Namespace.  Again googling both will provide you with the answers.  This is basic research for any developer.

Comment: their is a lot to work for me to improve..thanks alot for your words..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you might need to search on google before posting your question on stack overflow regarding `Zend_Session_Namespace`. There are no. of article available on google. But still here is some sort of basic guidance for you about Zend_Session_Namespace.

The Zend Framework provides advanced session handling using the `Zend_Session` component. Using this component, you no longer need to access PHP's `$_SESSION` global variable.

`Zend_Session` uses namespaces to store your session data. That is, when you want to read or write session data you must first specify a namespace. This allows you to easily store different session data without worrying too much about other values stored in the session.

Example:

```
<?php
    require_once('Zend/Session.php');
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('identity');

    //You can used it like this:

    $username= $session->username;
    $userid= $userid;
?>
```

Read [Zend Session Namespace from zend framework's documentation for more details](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html)

`$a=new Zend_Session_Namespace(Zend_Registry::get('session_variable'));`

The above code means : You set your session in zend registry by using zend_registry's set method somewhere (might be in bootstrap) and you are accessing it by using `zend_registry's` get method.

If you are new in Zend Framework I recommend you to please go through following tutorial.

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Basic-Tutorial-P840.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/reference.html

Hope it'll help you.